# Is there a forcing extension $M[G]$ of $M$ that adds a new $\omega$-sized subset to $\omega_2$ without adding any new subsets of $\omega$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

I should add that the forcing extension must preserve the cardinals $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$.

Note that such a forcing extension cannot add any new $\omega$-sized subsets to $\omega_1$, and also cannot be $\omega$-distributive.

If necessary, you may assume $M \models GCH$.

I suppose that the question arises from my wondering about if a forcing extension not add any new subsets of $\omega$, must it also not add any new $\omega$-sized subsets to anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look into Namba forcing.

This forcing changes the cofinality of $\omega_2$ to be countable, and assuming $\sf CH$ it does that without adding new reals. In particular $\omega_1$ is preserved.

Comment: Note that the CH assumption is necessary - if I have an injection $f: \omega_2\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ (in $M$), then -  if $h\in M[G]$ is an $\omega$-sequence of elements of $\omega_2$ - the map $\langle n_0, n_1\rangle\mapsto f(h(n_0))(n_1)$ is a real in $M[G]$ but not in $M$.

Comment: @vhspdfg How so? Namba forcing does not preserve $\aleph_2$.

Comment: @Andres: On the dangers of writing an answer when you just woke up and still lie in bed...

Comment: @Andrés It still addressed the more general question from which my specific one arose, which was fine enough for me at the time. And Miha below answered the natural generalization of my question completely, which is fantastic.

Answer (score 8):

If you insist that both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are preserved then this is impossible. The reason is that, since $\omega_2$ is preserved and, in particular, remains regular in $M[G]$, any countable subset $X$ of it in the extension must be bounded. But given a bound $\alpha<\omega_2$, we can fix in $M$ a bijection $f\colon \omega_1\to\alpha$. Then $X\subseteq\omega_2$ is new iff $f^{-1}[X]\subseteq\omega_1$ is new, but as you state (or following a version of Noah's argument), there can be no new subsets of $\omega_1$.

If you allow $\omega_2$ to be collapsed then Asaf's Namba forcing suggestion works (at least under CH). Allowing $\omega_1$ to be collapsed doesn't really make sense, since collapsing it will just add a real.

Interesting things start to happen when you try to replace $\omega_2$ with larger cardinals $\kappa$. If you want cardinals to be preserved, the argument above tells you that $\kappa$ cannot remain regular (or even of uncountable cofinality) in the extension (in particular, this cannot work for any successor $\kappa$). Jensen covering voodoo then says that you should really have something like a measurable running around. But if we have a measurable $\kappa$ then Prikry forcing at $\kappa$ is exactly the type of thing you are looking for: it preserves cardinals, does not add bounded subsets of $\kappa$, but does add an (unbounded) countable subset to $\kappa$.

Comment: One final resort, I should add here, is that the axiom of choice fails and $\omega_2$ is measurable, e.g. under AD. Then you can really do Prikry forcing on $\omega_2$ and change its cofinality to $\omega$ without collapsing any cardinals below it.